# Why is the chrome extension not updating without removing it?

Tags: google-chrome, webpack, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension built using webpack.

When I make some code changes (in developer mode) and rebuild the extension, sometimes it updates automatically (I just need to close and reopen the ext icon.). Sometimes I need to reinstall the extension in order to apply the changes.
I tried to find a connection, but I could not find anything, it is completely random.

But **worst of all**, when I upload an extension to the Google Chrome store, I have the same situation. **Users must completely delete and reinstall the extension for new features.**

Who knows what it depends on and how to fix it?

Comment: update button doesn't help

Comment: Probably https://crbug.com/1271154.